# Get the value of a int after a timeline

Tags: java, javafx, timeline

I have an application whose goal is to roll a die, I use a TimeLine but I don't know how to get the value of the die at the end of it in another class.
Here is my code:
In class Dice

```
private List <Image> listeFaceDice;
private int randomNum;
private ImageView imageView;
public void dropDice(){
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), event -> {
        setRandomNum(rand.nextInt(6);
        imageView.setImage(listeFaceDice.get(randomNum-1));
    }));
    timeline.setCycleCount(6);
    timeline.play();
    timeline.setOnFinished(e -> {
        setRandomNum(randomNum);
    });

}
```

In class Game

```
public Button getBtnDropDice() {
    if(btnDropDice == null) {
        btnDropDice = new Button("Drop dice");
        btnDropDice.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Dice dice = new Dice();
                    dice.dropDice();
                    System.out.println(dice.getRandomNum());
            }
        });
    }
    return btnDropDice;
}
```

Comment: assuming setRandomNum actually set randomNum, all you need a public method getRandomNum() that returns randomNum;

Comment: Yes, I have one but when I'm in the class Game after rolldice. The value that is recovered is 0.

Comment: the value doesn't get converted to 0, you are most likely creating a new object which will return default value 0 for integer,

you need to make sure you create the object once only and reuse the same object. 
e.g. object as an attribute

Comment: The random number is not determined at the time `dropDice` returns. You could of course determine the number sequence during the method call allowing you to get the last result even before the timeline starts animating. Otherwise you'd need to add a `onFinished` event handler to the `Timeline` to execute code after the timeline is done...

Comment: The `onFinished` handler of course needs to contain the code for reacting to the final result (the `println` in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually already access the value once the dice roll is finished: you just don't do anything with it (other than call `setRandomNum(...)`, which doesn't do anything as you pass the value that is already set).

If you replace that handler with a `System.out.println(...)` you will see the value in the console:

```
timeline.setOnFinished(e -> {
    System.out.println(randomNum);
});
```

If you want to do something with it back in the calling class, first note of course that the `dropDice()` method will exit immediately (i.e. before the animation completes). One thing you can do is to pass the `dropDice()` method a function that processes the result:

```
public void dropDice(IntConsumer valueProcessor){
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), event -> {
        setRandomNum(rand.nextInt(6);
        imageView.setImage(listeFaceDice.get(randomNum-1));
    }));
    timeline.setCycleCount(6);
    timeline.play();
    timeline.setOnFinished(e -> {
        valueProcessor.accept(randomNum);
    });

}
```

Now you can do:

```
Dice dice = new Dice();
dice.dropDice(diceValue -> {
    // do whatever you need to do with diceValue here. 
    // Just as a demo:
    System.out.println("Value rolled was "+diceValue);
});
```

The function (more precisely, the `accept(...)` method in the `IntConsumer`) you pass to `dropDice()` here will be invoked on the FX Application Thread (so it is safe to update the UI) once the dice roll has finished.

Comment: Thank you, it works but you can explain in a few words what a IntConsumer?

Comment: @Fapinski https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/IntConsumer.html Also see "Approach 7" in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @James_D!